# How should I structure my git-svn workflow to avoid "revision1 is merged into revision2, but does not have git-svn metadata"

Tags: version-control, git-svn

I am using git-svn in my workplace since our current version control server is subversion and switching completely to git does not seem to be on the horizon for now (*cry*)

My workflow is as follows
I have the following branches

- master tracks remotes/trunk
- local/0.4 tracks remotes/0.4
- work is my development branch for the master branch
- work-0.4 is my development branch for the local/0.4 branch

I work in my work branches, then I merge to master and local/0.4 using

```
git merge --no-ff <branchname>
```

After that I check in to svn via

```
git svn dcommit
```

and I use

```
svn.pushmergeinfo=true
```

to update the svn:mergeinfo properties so my colleagues won't get angry with me messing up that metadata for them :)

However, I just had the following problem which stumps me.

I had done two commits on the work-0.4 branch, then I merged these to my local/0.4 branch with git merge --no-ff work-0.4. After this, I did git svn dcommit and recieved the following message

```
Committing to https://svn-server ...
e138050f6ebd2f2ca99cbefc5e48acae412e1f86 is merged into revision f5f2345e8e5fc64
20423bdc00397b5853b3759c4, but does not have git-svn metadata. Either dcommit the
branch or use a local cherry-pick, FF merge, or rebase instead of 
an explicit merge commit.
```

After some rebasing and reset'ing of branches I managed to push everything to svn, but my solution entailed doing a rebase of my local/0.4 branch to the work-0.4 branch which in turn meant that I did not get to squash my two git-commits into one svn-commit :/

I feel that I'm probably doing something wrong with my workflow here, and it might be related to svn.pushmergeinfo. The docs for svn.pushmergeinfo says

```
config key: svn.pushmergeinfo
+
This option will cause git-svn to attempt to automatically populate the
svn:mergeinfo property in the SVN repository when possible. Currently, this can
only be done when dcommitting non-fast-forward merges where all parents but the
first have already been pushed into SVN.
```

and to be honest, I'm not quite sure that I understand that correctly? Am I doing something weird here that makes svn.pushmergeinfo not work correctly? How should I structure my workflow to optimally work with git-svn correctly (setting proper mergeinfos etc)?

Comment: Removing svn.pushmergeinfo=true from my config avoid the "but does not have git-svn metadata", but don't think it's a feasible solution.